# Cancelling thread in async/await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am trying to test a small app that is using async/await to process transactions **and** using an await/async polling feature.

My test setup:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProcessTimerOnly()
    {
        // this initializes and kicks off the polling
        var tp = new TransactionProcessor();

        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            tp.CancelProcessing();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErrors(ref tp, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            DisplayLog(tp);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestProcessTimerOnlyForcedCancellation()
    {
        // this initializes and kicks off the polling
        var tp = new TransactionProcessor(1);

        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            tp.CancelProcessing();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErrors(ref tp, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            DisplayLog(tp);
        }
    }
```

My code (all in one class):

```
    // Constructor
    public TransactionProcessor(int? debugForcedCancellationDelay = null)
    {
// >>>>>>>> Setup Cancellation <<<<<<<<
        if(debugForcedCancellationDelay.IsEmpty() || debugForcedCancellationDelay.IsZeroOrLess())
            _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        else
            _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(debugForcedCancellationDelay.Value));
// >>>>>>>> End <<<<<<<<

// was:
        // RepeatActionEvery(() => TestingLog.Add("Repeat Action Every 1 Second"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _cancellationToken.Token).Wait();
// corrected:
        // _processTask is defined as a global field of type Task...
        _processTask = RepeatActionEvery(() => TestingLog.Add("Repeat Action Every 1 Second"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _cancellationToken.Token);    //.Wait();
    }

// was:
    //public void CancelProcessing()
// corrected:
    public async Task CancelProcessing()
    {
        _cancellationToken.Cancel();
        await _processTask;
    }
    public static async Task RepeatActionEvery(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            action();
            var task = Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken);

            try { await task; }
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { return; }
        }
    }
```

When I run the TestProcessTimerOnly() test, it will just sit there until I finally cancel the test rig.

When I run the TestProcessTimerOnlyForcedCancellation() test, it behaves as expected.

So the questions boils down to:  Am I using the _cancellationToken variable properly?  In one instance, I initialize it **with** a timeout param.  In the other instance I initialize it with no params.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the code for your other constructor that you are calling? The constructor you show doesn't match the constructor used in the tests...

Comment: Forgot to remove the boolean when I pasted here.  Corrected my question to match my actual code.

Comment: Note that your `try ... catch (TaskCanceledException)` should cover the `Task.Delay` as well, as that will throw it when cancellation occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using ["sync over async"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) which is highly discouraged.

### What you are doing

You are getting a task out of `RepeatActionEvery` that will end only when the cancellation token is canceled. But you are waiting synchronously (**blocking**) on that task, which means that you would never get out of the constructor and reach the line cancelling the token (`tp.CancelProcessing();`).

Of course when you create the `CancellationTokenSource` with a timeout, it will cancel itself eventually without you having to invoke it, so the task will end, the thread waiting on it will be free to finish the constructor and call `tp.CancelProcessing();`

### What you want to be doing

What you should probably do (IIUC) is store the transaction task without waiting for it and await only when you cancel (or finish) the transaction:

```
public TransactionProcessor(int? debugForcedCancellationDelay = null)
{
    // ...
    Task = RepeatActionEvery(
        () => TestingLog.Add("Repeat Action Every 1 Second"), 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
        _cancellationToken.Token);
}

public async Task CancelProcessingAsync()
{
    _cancellationToken.Cancel();
    await Task;
}
```

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the link!  I'll update my code sample (above) to reflect the changes I made that now works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is because in the first example you have blocked all threads with the .Wait() so nothing actually happens because it is stuck waiting.  The reason it works in the second example is because you have set the cancellationToken to cancel after 1 second.  This "wait" on the cancellation token's part is on a different thread so it can still run.

Using .Wait or Thread.Sleep will block ALL threads.  Since all of your logic is on the same thread, you are stuck.  Using Task.Run().Wait() around your RepeatEveryAction(() =>) call (without the .Wait()) should clear it up because the logic will be put onto another thread to run.

Comment: Note, the only reason to use .Wait() here at all is because (assuming here) that you are using a console application and you dont want it to terminate before the async actions complete.  In general, should not call .Wait() because it blocks threads.  Using await and/or Task.WhenAll is best.

Comment: Oops...no.  Will only block the thread the blocking call is made on. Not sure what I was thinking there.